# How do you get the very first boot messages smaller?

Tags: boot, grub2, display-resolution, text, framebuffer

How do I get the very first boot messages, before the decryption of the system and before uvesafb is loaded, smaller? I tried:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768
```

and

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x8
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768x8
```

and

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:640x480"
```

the same as hex code (is supported according to `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer`),

in `/etc/default/grub`

and

```
  set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}    
  set gfxpayload=keep
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod vbe
```

in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`. And of course, always `sudo update-grub2`.

The letters are still very big. Some of the above possibilities even result in a black screen before uvesafb is loaded.

Version: `grub-mkconfig (GRUB) 1.99-12ubuntu5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved without me changing anything, I guess by a kernel update around 3.0.0.16. The text is now small, just how I like it. Maybe it was a kernel bug.

Answer (score 2):

Provided your screen resolution is 1024x768 you should only need to add

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

to `/etc/default/grub` and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Here is the diff of my grub file and the original one (my resolution is 1280x1024
):

```
$ diff /etc/default/{grub,grub.bak}
25,26c25
< GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
< GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
---
> #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Comment: I tried that (grub-setup including), but no success. The resolution stays the same. My native resolution is 1366x768, but I tried 1024x768.

Comment: So you tried with GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768 and that didn't work? I don't know what else to try then.